# Listbox blank when trying to load SQL, SQL string loads correctly

Tags: sql, vba, forms, ms-access, listview

I have a list box that populates based on a value set in a textbox. My form has 2 text boxes, first name and last name, the user would enter 1 or both values and the list box populates with the information. However, my list box is not populating.

When I step through the code, the SQL string will register the correct string with the values entered from the text boxes, but is showing zero for the list count.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim SQL As String

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    
    If IsNull(Me.txtSearchLname) Or Me.txtSearchLname = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter a Last Name", vbInformation, "Required Data"
        Me.txtSearchLname.SetFocus
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
        Exit Sub
    Else
    
        If IsNull(Me.txtSearchFName) Or Me.txtSearchFName = "" Then
            SQL = "SELECT PartPRNR AS PERNR, [PartSS#] AS SSN, PartFName AS FirstName, PartLName AS LastName, WORKAdd1 AS WorkAddress FROM TBLparticipants " & _
                  "WHERE PartLName LIKE '" & apostrophe(UCase(txtSearchLname)) & "%' ORDER BY PartFName"
        Else
            SQL = "SELECT PartPRNR AS PERNR, [PartSS#] AS SSN, PartFName AS FirstName, PartLName AS LastName, WORKAdd1 AS WorkAddress FROM TBLparticipants " & _
                  "WHERE PartLName LIKE '" & apostrophe(UCase(txtSearchLname)) & "%' AND PartFName LIKE '" & apostrophe(UCase(txtSearchFName)) & "%' ORDER BY PartFName"
                   
        Me.lstSearchResults.RowSource = SQL
        
    End If
    
    If lstSearchResults.ListCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Search did not return any results!", vbInformation, "System"
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
    End If
    
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    
    
Exit Sub:
    booMDDRFlag = True
    
  End Sub
```

Any ideas? Appreciate the help.

Comment: `& "% AND'PartFName LIKE '" &`  should probably be `& "%' AND PartFName LIKE '" &`   What does `apostrophe` do?

Comment: Does the generated SQL return any records if you run it directly?

Comment: You must force the list to query after updating the rowsource. `lstSearchResults.Requery`

Comment: In a query window, yes. If the values are entered directly into the query.

Comment: @RicardoA It is still coming up blank.

Comment: Do a msgbox SQL after the IF statement, does the query look right to you?

Comment: @RicardoA yes. It's completely accurate.

Comment: Change the query to a simple one. just SELECT * FROM [Table] and check if it loads. if it doesnt then it may be a property of the List which doesnt update when updating the RowSource property.

Comment: @RicardoA That worked as a select query and it loaded. So is it something to do with the SQL string you think?

Comment: Wildcard in Access is * not %

Comment: Except when linked table is SQLServer, either wildcard works - at least it does for me in my db.

Comment: Late last night I found an article referencing the wildcard. Changed that and it worked like a charm. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Either wildcard might work if you using ADO, but with DAO and linked tables, then you continue to use *, and not %. so, with ADO, then yes, % is used, but using DAO, then you continue to use the access wild card of *